# How to configure Spring 3 in weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: weblogic-10.x, spring-3

How to configure Spring 3 to Weblogic 10.3.5.
     Currently I get this exception.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

Answer (score 0):

There's no add method on that class in Spring 2.5, according to the javadocs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.html

But there is in version 3:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/

Sounds like you have a mix of versions 2.5 and 3.x that is incorrect.